# Drupal View - Like Google Images Search

Tags: jquery, css, drupal, google-image-search

I'm trying to create a catalogue for my content, that has a similar function to google image search. ie. When you click an icon/image, the rows underneath shift down and the expanded content for that image is displayed.

Can this be done by CSS only or does it need to be set up a specific way first

*edit: I understand the showing/hiding is done by javascript, but I meant can I make a div appear and push down the rows underneath it, rather than just pushing down the column underneath it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with pure CSS, you will need javascript to react to the click event.

Comment: Thanks for your input, what I meant can I make a div that would push down the rest of the content rows when you click on an individual item?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be a div each after each result row and when you click a image above that div then make that extra div appear through jQuery and content in it.

Here are jQuery effects that you may want to use :
http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/